# htaccess: stop htaccess work in all folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need some help in this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This code change all rewrite urls from

> /test-post-name
>
> /index.php?url=test-post-name

but it affect all folders

mean

i have vb in this path

`site.com/vb`

but the url apper like

`site.com/vb/?url=`

how can i fix this

to be
`site.com/vb/index.php`  **or** `site.com/vb`

Comment: Please be more specific, precise which URLs you want to modify, which URLs you want to leave untouched.

Comment: i mean my let my htaccess code work in the main index file  and diable in all other paths like  `/vb` and `/upload`

Comment: So use a filter that just takes everything when there's no other `/`. Something like **`RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ ...blabla...`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rewrite will only take place if the request not points to a valid directory or file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

To disable any rewrites inside your `/vb` folder you could add a `.htaccess` into that folder and turn of the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d`    **should here put my vb paths   right????**

Comment: All three lines should go in one `.htaccess` thats in the same path as your `index.php` file and then no rewrites will be performed for anything that is a valid path or file i.e `/vb` won't get rewritten

Comment: thank you , but i just copied you code  but it still work like this     `site.com/vb`   to  `site.com/vb/?url=vb` here is the link `http://www.wady-malaysia.com` and this link `http://www.wady-malaysia.com/vb`   redirect to `http://www.wady-malaysia.com/vb/?url=vb`

Comment: I edited my post and added a `RewriteBase` directive, you should also try to empty your browsers cache.

Comment: Thank you ,i think its browser cache now , because i requested another path and it work fine  but vb  still redirect :( , i will empty my browser cache now , thanks again